# What is is the maximum number of threads that I can use for a server?

Tags: multithreading, server

I want to use 8 threads to run a program. The information of my server is as follow.

number of physical CPU:
2
number of CPU core:
cpu cores   : 4
number of processor:
16

So how many cores of the server can I use at one time at most?

Comment: You have your terminology all messed up and it's unclear what you are asking. Are you creating a multithreaded program?

Answer (score 1):

If they are all *compute bound*, about 8   (the 16 is coming from hyper-threading, i.e., fake cores).  if the threads are IO bound you can have a lot more.

Comment: How can I know if the server is IO bound or CPU bound? Thanks.

Comment: That depends on the tasks that the threads are doing. It is your code I imagine. If the threads are doing computations or doing IO should be pretty clear from the code of the threads.